# How pass session variables between two or more aspx pages?

Tags: asp.net

My Scenario,

Im using asp.net 2.0 .I have Site where it creates a unique id and it is inserted in Database and displaying in Textbox that is invisible. Now i need to send this Id to next Page. i Used Session("MemberId") = Txtnewid.Text. Its not working It shows zero value when i assign to variable string. Please Help Me . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to store the value in a textbox at all. All you need to do is take the id and insert it in session the first time is created; on subsequent requests on the same page or any other within your site, you can access this id by doing:

```
string id = Session["MemberId"] as string;
```

Or in Vb syntax:

```
dim id as String = Session("MemberId")
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming C# in codebehind, set the session variable like :-

```
      Session["MemberId"] = "MemberId";
```

Get it back into the next page as ;-

```
 if (Session["MemberId"] != null)
  {
    textBox1.Text = "Successfully retrieved " + (string)Session["MemberId"];
  }
```

Do read about [ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx#Y684)

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to transfer the values from one page to another. The most frequent methods are

1. Session
2. QueryString

1.aspx.cs // First Page

```
Guid uniqueid = new Guid();

//Above code line will generate the unique id

string s_uniqueid = uniqueid.ToString();

// Convert the guid into string format

Session.Add("MemberId",s_uniqueid);

// Store the string unique id string to session variable so far called MemberId
```

2.asp.cs // Second Page

```
string s_MemberId = Session["MemberId"].ToString();
Now you can use this string member id for any other process.
```

Or

Use querystring to transfer the values from one page to another
If you are developing application using asp.net ajax, then you need to use Response.Redirect Method else Server.Transfer

Like
1.aspx.cs // First Page

```
Guid uniqueid = new Guid();

//Above code line will generate the unique id

string s_uniqueid = uniqueid.ToString();
```

If you wish, use encryption of s_uniqueid

```
Response.Redirect("2.aspx?uid=" +s_uniqueid+ "");
```

2.asp.cs // Second Page

```
string ss_uniqueid = Request.QueryString["s_uniqueid"];
```

then use for another process

Answer (score 1):

Use query string to transfer the values from one page to another. If you are developing application using ASP.NET ajax, then you need to use `Response.Redirect` method else `Server.Transfer`.